# :hover isn't applying full background to li

Tags: html, list, css

My navigation has dropdowns, and within them there are a tags wrapping the items. I want the hover background color to be applied when I hover over that entire li. Right now it's only applying to the li, and when I move off the text it's the other background color.

Live here: http://stage.christinas-kitchen.com/

I'm working under "recipes", if you look under sprinkles that is how it should work (I have nothing wrapped in an a tag yet).

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the styles in your stylesheet is

```
.nav ul li ul li a {
    background: #6ac4c2;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

That is your problem; since the `a` has its own background color, and the `a` is a child of the the `li`, changing the `li`'s background color does not influence the `a`'s background color.

You really just want the `li` styles to be determining the background color of your menu items, **so just remove the `background` attribute from that style declaration.** That way, the `a`'s background will be dictated by the parent `li`, and your menus should work how you want them to